# Microsoft Word legacy template, need to find add-in code

Tags: xml, ms-word, add-in, legacy

My group has a legacy (Word 2003) .dot template that we use for formatting documents and adding repetitive text.

On the Add-ins tab, it has a custom toolbar with drop down menus that allow you to select certain text entries to put in the document.

I am trying to add additional items to the drop down menus (using Word 2010 now), but for the life of me I can't figure out where the code is to edit them. I've looked in the developer tab, but I can't see any VBA code that would generate the toolbar.

I searched on here, and found some articles that said to save the file as a .dotm and then change the extension to .zip and you can look at the .xml files inside. Looking in there, the only reference I could find with anything related to the add-ins was document.xml which had a massive amount of XML code to dig through.

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question in the right way, so I can try to elaborate more in needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research yesterday, I concluded that this was not possible.

I am in the process of using the Custom UI Editor and VBA code to rewrite the functionality of the old template.